# asp how to get the current page reference from a web service method?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax

i'm in a slideshow extender web service method and trying to get a stringfrom the request.QueryString that i got in page_load.
of course new myPage() won't do.
so what can i do?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can store the querystring in the Session on page load and access it from your service when necessary.
2. You can store the applicable parts of the query string in a hidden field on the page and pass the values along as part of your service call.
3. If the querystring is still a part of the URL when you want to make the service call, you can extract the values from the url with javascript and pass them along.

Comment: thanks but even when i enablesession=true i can't reach session in my webservice. what am i missing?                          [WebMethod (EnableSession=true)]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public static AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] GetSlides()
    {
        string Name =(string) Session["name"];//session is unreachable

Comment: i got it from [link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/7/10041446/how-to-enable-session-in-webservices.aspx) reached it throough HttpContext.Current.Session thanks